# Report Designer Solutions?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, reporting-services, crystal-reports

We are looking for Report Designer for end users NOT for developers. Domain : .Net

We are looking for Report Builder into Application so that end user can design reports at run time and Save them and reload them.

Any good recommendation for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik Reporting](http://demos.telerik.com/reporting/home.aspx) could potentially suit your needs.

Comment: I am not looking for predefined reports given by Developers to End Users and End Users hit "Refresh". I am looking for very flexible solution where user can drag drop fields from data source and create reports and create chart out of that data at run time; also they should be able to change report type and run time itself and then they should be able to save that report...

Comment: I'm about 75% certain there's capabilities for that

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Cognos Query Studio or similar.